# Can two continuous random variables not be jointly continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

In my book, lots of statements begin with "Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly continuous random variables." and then some example or a derivation of a formula follows. But can two continuous random variables not be jointly continuous? What does it mean for two continuous random variables to not be jointly continuous? Does it have something to do with the sample spaces on which they are defined on?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226648/problem-about-jointly-continuous-and-linearity-of-expectation. Did's answer addresses two continuous random variables not being jointly continuous, and an example of this

Comment: Thank you, but the $X=Y$ case seems a bit dull to me for some reason. Can $X$ and $Y$ be different and not jointly continuous as well?

Comment: Sure: $X = 2 + 3Y.$   Still a bit dull?

Comment: @BruceET That'll do it I suppose, thank you. How should one go about proving that they are not jointly continuous?